# Why does enzyme find a a node on one line and then not on the next

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, enzyme

I have a simple enzyme test which checks that a HTML input password field is empty and then tries to type some text into it as follows.

```
expect(wrapper.find({type: 'password'})).toHaveLength(0);
wrapper.find({type: 'password'}).simulate('keydown', {which: "password123"});
```

The first line runs fine and passes. However the second line fails and reports the following error.

> ***Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.***

How can enzyme find the component on one line and not the next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line passes, because it checks the length of the found elements, not the length of its content. Seems like 0 elements have been found (so the first line passes).

You can check the rendered DOM with `wrapper.debug()`, you can check there, if the password input is present in the shallow wrapper or not.

Comment: My apologies. I misunderstood the API.